# How to print a specific amount of strings such as "_"?

Tags: java

I need to print a specific set of lines without manually typing them.
I want my output to be like this

"|Word_***_*__*_*____**|"

Is there a code which allows me to set my own amount of "_"?

Comment: And what have you tried? At least created project in workplace?

Comment: Yes there is.  Please try something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One may use a format, which then padds (left or right) with spaces.

```
System.out.printf("|%-30s|%5s|%n", "Aa", "1");
System.out.printf("|%-30s|%5s|%n", "Bbbb", "222");

String s = String.format("|%-30s|%5s|%n", "Aa", "1").replace(' ', '_');

String fortyBlanks = String.format("%40s", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

No direct way. But with looping you can do

```
String s = "";
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // sample 10
    s = s + "_";
    }
System.out.println(s);
```

Still it is not a bestway to use `+` in looping. Best way is

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {  //sample 10
        b.append("_");
    }
System.out.println(b.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print a `_` with:

```
System.out.print("_");
```

If you want more, do it multiple times (inefficient), or build up a string containing multiple and print it. You may want to look at [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop.

Here's the link to the java documnentation for a `for` loop: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Answer (score -1):

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int amountOf_ = 10;
        System.out.println("|" + StringUtils.rightPad("Word", amountOf_, "_") + "|");
    }
}
```